# VBA match value from from workbook A & B, return another value from workbook B

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have 2 workbooks A & B.

Workbook A is list of customer invoices (5000 rows). customer ID is at column A.
Workbook B is customer details, comprising 15000 rows and 100 columns. Customer ID is at column B.

Using customer ID, i tried to copy data from column D,E,G,O,AA,AD,AF,BD,CA (customers' address, phones,emails) found in workbook B to workbook A column F to N.

I have been using vlookup for this but it is too time consuming as data gets refreshed daily and I need to re-enter the formula time and again.

I tried to use VBA Loop function but it timed out (data too big). I tried various ways like match function I cant seem to get the result.

Below is the code i tried. I am sorry I am super new to VBA. I think double loop is not encouraged for such big data. customer data has 100 columns and 14000 rows, invoice has 3000 rows

```
Sub CustomerData()

Dim r As Long
Dim r1 As Long
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sheet2 As Worksheet

Dim FilePath1 As String
FilePath1 = Range("Q1").Value

Workbooks.Open (FilePath1 & "invoice.xlsx")
Workbooks.Open (FilePath1 & "customer.xls")
Set sheet1 = Workbooks("customer.xls").Worksheets("Customers")
Set sheet2 = Workbooks("invoice.xlsx").Worksheets("unpaid_invoices")

r = 0

Do
    r1 = 0
    Do
        If sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 0) Then
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 13) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 8)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 14) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 9)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 15) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 38)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 16) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 64)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 17) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 25)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 18) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 39)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 19) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 41)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 20) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 44)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 21) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 78)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 22) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 99)
        sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 23) = sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 100)
        End If
    r1 = r1 + 1
    Loop Until sheet1.Range("B1").Offset(r1, 0).Value = ""
r = r + 1
Loop Until sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(r, 0).Value = ""
End Sub
```

I have been searching the website for a day, I cant seem to get what I want. I will be happy if someone can point me to the right direction

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you tried.

Comment: Hi YowE3K. Thank you for alert. I have added the code. I apologize I am still very new to vba and to this website

Answer (score 0):

With this magnitude of Data I would encourage you to look into PowerQuery, which is included in Excel 2016 and available as an AddIn since Excel 2010.

[First Table called "Invoices", Second called "Details"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pD3ig.png)

Add the two tables to Power Query (Excel 2016: "Data" Ribbon --> "Get & Transform" Section --> "From Table" or "New Query"->"From Workbook")

[And then in Power Query Editor use "Merge Queries":](https://i.stack.imgur.com/golfp.png)

Select the columns you wish to add to your table

Then Click "Save and Load To" and Select the destination for the merged table.

This is very performant and by clicking "Refresh All" will keep the new table in sync.

P.S. I would post more pictures, but dont have the "reputation"

Best

Florian